# Extract specific objects from json array mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a JSON column 'cart_data' with following data :

```
[{
    "type": 2,
    "amount": 500
}, {
    "type": 1,
    "amount": 600
},
, {
    "type": 1,
    "amount": 700
}]
```

I want to fetch cart_data column which contains type 1 and output should be :

```
[{
    "type": 1,
    "amount": 600
},
{
    "type": 1,
    "amount": 700
}]
```

Basically I want to remove objects which has type other than 1 (in this example).

Here's what I've been trying :

```
SELECT  order_id , 
        json_remove(json_extract(cart_data, '$[*]'),'$[0]') as cart_data 
from billing 
where json_contains(cart_data->'$[*].type', json_array(1));
```

In above query, 2nd parameter for json_remove is static. I want to make it dynamic to remove all objects which doesn't have type : 1

Any possibilities?

Thanks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , This is not relevant to my question. Please remove duplicate mark.

I am looking for a mysql solution!

Comment: WHat version of MySQL are you using

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am using v5.7

Comment: Edited, please check now.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly

Comment: All you had to do was show you had attempted something, so the question did not look like a DIFM

Comment: Yes, understood.